# Performing a wilcox test in R for unpaired data

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the wilcox test in R to establish if there's a significant difference between two unpaired datasets as given below. I know the data below is normally distributed but my original data is not normally distributed.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(10, 4, 1)
x2 <- rnorm(10, 7, 1)

wilcox.test(x1, x2)


Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x2
W = 1, p-value = 2.165e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

I've also tried the below code but its giving an error report

```
wilcox.test(x1 ~ x2)
Error in wilcox.test.formula(x1 ~ x2) : 
grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

My question is-is this the right approach for this data?-I think its doing a rank sum test-is this what I should be getting. The p-values suggests that there is a significant difference between the two data sets.

Comment: The error message of the formula method is descriptive. The RHS of the formula is expected to be a grouping factor. Also, if your data is normal distributed (as in your example) there is no reason to use a non-parametric test. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Read `?wilcox.test` If you are going to use the `formula` version, then your `x2` must be of class `factor` with exactly two elements. Since you haven't explained what you want to do, nor shown any results, I can't comment on your choice of approach.

Comment: choice is between t.test(x1,x2) and wilcox.test(x1,x2). If there are small number of values, wilcox may be better.

Comment: @Roland, lets just assume that my data is not normally distributed-my original dataset is not normally distributed which will make a wilcox test suitable.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I see-I get it now. I'm only trying to see if there's a significant difference between the two data sets x1 and x2 as given in my question. I'll edit the post to include results. It turns out there is a difference btw the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following demonstrates use of formula in wilcox.test using same data:

```
> dd = data.frame(x1,x2)
> library(reshape2)
> melt(dd)
No id variables; using all as measure variables
   variable    value
1        x1 3.373546
2        x1 4.183643
3        x1 3.164371
4        x1 5.595281
5        x1 4.329508
6        x1 3.179532
7        x1 4.487429
8        x1 4.738325
9        x1 4.575781
10       x1 3.694612
11       x2 8.511781
12       x2 7.389843
13       x2 6.378759
14       x2 4.785300
15       x2 8.124931
16       x2 6.955066
17       x2 6.983810
18       x2 7.943836
19       x2 7.821221
20       x2 7.593901
> with(melt(dd), wilcox.test(value~variable))
No id variables; using all as measure variables

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  value by variable
W = 1, p-value = 2.165e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

The result is same as with wilcox.test(x1,x2)

```
> wilcox.test(x1,x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x2
W = 1, p-value = 2.165e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: I'm guessing melt is from the reshape package?

Comment: thanks for your answer-sometimes its so difficult to put into words what the coding problem is. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, melt is from reshape2. Added in the answer above.